# React Native start failed with error code -4094 how to solve this ONCE for ALL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm trying to run `react-native start` (as all the other days, it works normally) and it gives me this error:

**THE ERROR**

```
Loading dependency graph...events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\jest-util\node_modules\.bin\mkdirp'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:143:12)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\walker\lib\walker.js:52:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\OKR\\Desktop\\MeetUp App\\Development\\MeetUp2\\node_modules\\jest-util\\node_modules\\.bin\\mkdirp'
}
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~prestart: MeetUp2@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: MeetUp2@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\MinGW\bin;D:\Genymotion\tools;C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: CWD: C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp App\Development\MeetUp2
10 silly lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-native start' ]
11 silly lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: MeetUp2@0.0.1 start: `react-native start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid MeetUp2@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp App\Development\MeetUp2
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error MeetUp2@0.0.1 start: `react-native start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the MeetUp2@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- Deleted `node_modules` packages and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`. It still fails after many trials
- Update `node.js` to the latest-recommended version: `12.16.3`. Then repeat the above step and it still fails
- Run `npm cache clean` ( gives error) and reapeat step 1 --> Fail
- **EDIT 1** I have tried `react-native start --reset-cache` and it gives the same error
- **EDIT 2** I've tried: `npm cache clean --force` and it gives me error:

```
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\30\b7\d403a3bea9ab8b0dbca6fa631982d5c21917c8c72428787e88295705b25c8e0c47bf12524dc2bd05a21437c46e02e872ba6e4dca60f3d7c0754993757935
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\30\b7\d403a3bea9ab8b0dbca6fa631982d5c21917c8c72428787e88295705b25c8e0c47bf12524dc2bd05a21437c46e02e872ba6e4dca60f3d7c0754993757935'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-26T13_16_06_204Z-debug.log
```

*The logs*

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>   1 verbose cli [
>   1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>   1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>   1 verbose cli   'cache',
>   1 verbose cli   'clean',
>   1 verbose cli   '--force'
>   1 verbose cli ]
>   2 info using npm@6.14.4
>   3 info using node@v12.16.3
>   4 warn using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
>   5 verbose npm-session ec09bc51399022bd
>   6 verbose stack Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\30\b7\d403a3bea9ab8b0dbca6fa631982d5c21917c8c72428787e88295705b25c8e0c47bf12524dc2bd05a21437c46e02e872ba6e4dca60f3d7c0754993757935'
>   7 verbose cwd C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp App\Development\MeetUp2
>   8 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
>   9 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "cache" "clean" "--force"
>   10 verbose node v12.16.3
>   11 verbose npm  v6.14.4
>   12 error code UNKNOWN
>   13 error syscall unlink
>   14 error path C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\30\b7\d403a3bea9ab8b0dbca6fa631982d5c21917c8c72428787e88295705b25c8e0c47bf12524dc2bd05a21437c46e02e872ba6e4dca60f3d7c0754993757935
>   15 error errno -4094
>   16 error UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\30\b7\d403a3bea9ab8b0dbca6fa631982d5c21917c8c72428787e88295705b25c8e0c47bf12524dc2bd05a21437c46e02e872ba6e4dca60f3d7c0754993757935'
>   17 verbose exit [ -4094, true ]

(*I can't put the above log in code format since Stack Overflow doesn't allow to*)

- **EDIT 3:** I've tried  to run `cmd` in administrator mode but it throws the same error
- **EDIT 4:** I've tried `npm start` and it gives me this error:

```
Loading dependency graph...events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\jest-util\node_modules\.bin\mkdirp'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:143:12)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\walker\lib\walker.js:52:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\OKR\\Desktop\\MeetUp_App\\Development\\MeetUp2\\node_modules\\jest-util\\node_modules\\.bin\\mkdirp'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! MeetUp2@0.0.1 start: `react-native start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the MeetUp2@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-27T11_29_28_113Z-debug.log
```

**The logs:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~prestart: MeetUp2@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: MeetUp2@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\MinGW\bin;D:\Genymotion\tools;C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: CWD: C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2
10 silly lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-native start' ]
11 silly lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle MeetUp2@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: MeetUp2@0.0.1 start: `react-native start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid MeetUp2@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error MeetUp2@0.0.1 start: `react-native start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the MeetUp2@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

- **EDIT 5:** I've tried to run the command to upgrade react-native using `npx react-native upgrade`. And it gives this error:

```
info No version passed. Fetching latest...
info Fetching diff between v0.61.5 and v0.62.2...
info Applying diff...
warn Excluding files that exist in the template, but not in your project:

error Automatically applying diff failed. We did our best to automatically upgrade as many files as possible
warn Continuing after failure. Some of the files are upgraded but you will need to deal with conflicts manually
info Installing "react-native@0.62.2" and its peer dependencies...
error Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@0.62.2 react@16.11.0
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-27T11_26_44_748Z-debug.log
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@0.62.2 react@16.11.0
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\OKR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-27T11_26_44_748Z-debug.log

    at makeError (C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async installDeps (C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\upgrade\upgrade.js:206:3)
    at async Object.upgrade [as func] (C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\upgrade\upgrade.js:345:9)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\OKR\Desktop\MeetUp_App\Development\MeetUp2\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
```

**My** ***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "MeetUp2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^1.4.0",
    "@mapbox/polyline": "^1.1.0",

    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^4.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.7.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.1",

    "@ui-kitten/components": "^4.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-collapsingtoolbar": "^1.0.3",

    "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.7",

    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",

    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-keychain": "^6.0.0",

    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^14.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-share": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^3.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",

    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "uuid": "^8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
    "babel-jest": "^25.5.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.5.4",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**PLEASE HELP ME**

Comment: Have you tried clearing your Metro and react-native caches?  Try `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: I think it might be a permission issue that is preventing as your error log shows at line 11. Check the permission.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Yogesh. Can you please tell me what is that permission for and where can I check it?

Comment: Please paste your `package.json`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Ejaz. I've added the ```package.json```

Comment: have you tried running - `react-native run-android`. Can you check if its working. And I see blank lines in the `package.json`, you don't have any line commented in this file, right?

Comment: @Ejaz I've not tried running ```react-native run-android```. Also the blank lines are modified by me after the error and I'm sure they're not related to the error. Do you want me to provide the ```package-lock.json``` too? Yes I don't have any line commented in this file

Comment: You may have to try these steps in sequence to fix the issue - `rm -rf node_modules`, 
`rm package-lock.json yarn.lock`,  `npm cache clear --force`, `npm install`. [Source](https://peterthaleikis.com/posts/how-to-fix-throw-er-unhandled-error-event.html)

Comment: You have a folder name "MeetUp App". Can you try renaming the folder to something like "MeetUp-App" ? Just don't put space in folder name. And then try resetting and rebuilding the app again.

Comment: The actual root folder is ```MeetUp2``` which is contained in ```MeetUp App/Development```. I'll rename it and update the fix. Thanks for the comment @Tushar

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada I've rename that folder but the error still occurs. Please help me. I'm so desperate now

Comment: One way to resolve this could be to create a new project and copy all your project files only (dont copy package.json), then one by one install the dependencies :)

Comment: I know that. But it sucks. Since my code base is quite large ( up to 3-4k) and it has a lot of configuration with firebase admob and google maps, gradle for apk release ,etc. I just feel tired of doing that :'( . Do you know somebody who can solve this? @Ejaz

Comment: Note sure whether this helps or not. But package.json `name` convention looks like this: `The name must be less than 214 characters, must not have spaces, it can only contain lowercase letters, hyphens (-) or underscores (_).`

Comment: Thanks for the suggest @TusharKhatiwada I don't think it help but I'll try to change it's name. Please, if you know anyone that can solve this, help me let them know. By doing this, we're helping not just me but the whole react native community

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with the **npm cache**. Try the following solution:

Run the command: `npm cache verify`

If you get errors then run: `npm cache clear --force`

Right Click on **C: > Properties > Tools Tab**.

Select **Check** or **Check-now** under *Error Checking menu*.

Reboot your PC after the process is completed.

Comment: Hi @Tusharhatiwada . I own you. You saved me. Thank you sooooo much. It works super well.

Comment: @oriont Can you be more specific? You are having issue in windows or other OS. The solution is for windows PC. Which version of RN and all.

Comment: My RN version is 0.59.10 and yes, I was using the windows cmd prompt. I did find a way to get around it, which is to just use wsl instead. I don't like that solution though, because I didn't fix anything!