# Errors while updating to Angular 16

Tags: angular

I have got a problem while updating my angular project from version 15 to 16.
When I try to update it, I always get the following error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\WebContent\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/errors:865
npm ERR!   const err = new Error(message);
npm ERR!               ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\WebContent\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild --version
npm ERR! node:child_process:929
npm ERR!     throw err;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <ref *1> Error: spawnSync C:\Users\WebContent\node_modules\@esbuild\win32-x64\esbuild.exe UNKNOWN
npm ERR!     at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1117:20)
npm ERR!     at spawnSync (node:child_process:876:24)
npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:919:15)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\WebContent\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild:220:28)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)        
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10) 
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
npm ERR!   errno: -4094,
npm ERR!   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'spawnSync C:\\Users\\WebContent\\node_modules\\@esbuild\\win32-x64\\esbuild.exe',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\WebContent\\node_modules\\@esbuild\\win32-x64\\esbuild.exe',
npm ERR!   spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
npm ERR!   error: [Circular *1],
npm ERR!   status: null,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   output: null,
npm ERR!   pid: 0,
npm ERR!   stdout: null,
npm ERR!   stderr: null
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v18.18.0
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:890:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:926:15)
npm ERR!     at validateBinaryVersion (C:\Users\WebContent\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:98:28)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\WebContent\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:283:5 {
npm ERR!   status: 1,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   output: [
npm ERR!     null,
npm ERR!     Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
npm ERR!     Buffer(1567) [Uint8Array] [
npm ERR!       110, 111, 100, 101,  58,  99, 104, 105, 108, 100,  95, 112,        
npm ERR!       114, 111,  99, 101, 115, 115,  58,  57,  50,  57,  13,  10,        
npm ERR!        32,  32,  32,  32, 116, 104, 114, 111, 119,  32, 101, 114,        
npm ERR!       114,  59,  13,  10,  32,  32,  32,  32,  94,  13,  10,  13,        
npm ERR!        10,  60, 114, 101, 102,  32,  42,  49,  62,  32,  69, 114,        
npm ERR!       114, 111, 114,  58,  32, 115, 112,  97, 119, 110,  83, 121,        
npm ERR!       110,  99,  32,  67,  58,  92,  85, 115, 101, 114, 115,  92,        
npm ERR!       106, 117, 108, 105, 115, 116, 111, 101,  92, 101,  99, 108,        
npm ERR!       105, 112, 115, 101,
npm ERR!       ... 1467 more items
npm ERR!     ]
npm ERR!   ],
npm ERR!   pid: 22344,
npm ERR!   stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
npm ERR!   stderr: Buffer(1567) [Uint8Array] [
npm ERR!     110, 111, 100, 101,  58,  99, 104, 105, 108, 100,  95, 112,
npm ERR!     114, 111,  99, 101, 115, 115,  58,  57,  50,  57,  13,  10,
npm ERR!      32,  32,  32,  32, 116, 104, 114, 111, 119,  32, 101, 114,
npm ERR!      10,  60, 114, 101, 102,  32,  42,  49,  62,  32,  69, 114,
npm ERR!      10,  60, 114, 101, 102,  32,  42,  49,  62,  32,  69, 114,
npm ERR!     114, 111, 114,  58,  32, 115, 112,  97, 119, 110,  83, 121,
npm ERR!     110,  99,  32,  67,  58,  92,  85, 115, 101, 114, 115,  92,
npm ERR!     106, 117, 108, 105, 115, 116, 111, 101,  92, 101,  99, 108,
npm ERR!     105, 112, 115, 101,
npm ERR!     ... 1467 more items
npm ERR!   ]
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v18.18.0
```

It must have something to do with my @angular-devkit/build-angular dependency, because if i delete it from my package.json file it updates.

I have tried removing the nodes-modules and the package-lock file, but the error still occurs.

By the way, my package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "web-content",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng-chartjs": "^0.0.7",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.4",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "fs-monkey": "^1.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

Does somebody know how to fix this issue?

I have tried removing the nodes-modules and the package-lock file, but the error still occurs.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you resolve it? What happens if you remove @angular-devkit/build-angular, do the update, and then put it back?

Comment: Seems to be related https://stackoverflow.com/a/62044109/8144405

Comment: @Sergey -  That solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Seems very similar in nature to the reported issue here: https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/3156  Though this mainly affected docker images running node 20.3, but it had to do with a node issue introduced in that version.  I wonder if you go back to an earlier version of node 18 does it still happen?  I'm running 18.16 without an issue.

Comment: @mfaith - I'm on Node 18.12 and I still get the issue. Also, it seems esbuild is returning a different error in your link: -26/'ETXTBSY' as opposed to -4094/'UNKNOWN'.

Comment: How exactly are you updaing your angular? since you said that `if I remove @angular-devkit/build-angular` makes me think you are manually doing it. If so, try following these steps: https://update.angular.io/.
And double check your node version.

Comment: In your `angular.json` file, can you change all your references from @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild` to `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` ?

esbuild is still in the experimental stage in Angular 16. Your `ng build` will be slower when using `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` but there is a chance that it works. Try it out and let it me know