After successfully running my Storybook project on localhost in some time later I get the Error
[The error I am getting after running my storybook stencil project, Once I do npm start to run storybook it gives the localhost link but after some time it breaks and gives the error shown in image I have also mentioned the error below.
ERROR :
64% building 9/10 entries 225/226 dependencies 403/200 modulesD:\HB\AUI\Storybook Upgrade\aui-lakshay01\node_modules@storybook\cli\bin\index.js:23
throw error;
^
[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'D:\HB\AUI\Storybook Upgrade\aui-lakshay01\node_modules.cache\storybook\dev-server\a5a8bf6e622aef57065c6498611f40c911543d7d-a21314dc303cf26dabba6bf4a8fd381e47e44e94'] {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'D:\HB\AUI\Storybook Upgrade\aui-lakshay01\node_modules\.cache\storybook\dev-server\a5a8bf6e622aef57065c6498611f40c911543d7d-a21314dc303cf26dabba6bf4a8fd381e47e44e94'
}
Node.js v18.19.0
](https://i.sstatic.net/WI8zA.png)enter image description here
I am trying to migrate my project from storybook 6 to storybook 7 I have all the necessary changes but not sure what I've missed and needs to be done.
Whatever Components I have In my storybook taking a long time to load and not working properly.
Console Errors :
[There are the errors I am getting in Console (https://i.sstatic.net/nhETM.png)
The error I am getting after running my storybook stencil project, Once I do npm start to run storybook it gives the localhost link but after some time it breaks and gives the error shown in image I have also mentioned the error below.

Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015190/react-native-start-failed-with-error-code-4094-how-to-solve-this-once-for-all
Can you check npm cache verify?
